# How to group duplicate values to a single value and pull associated values with that column value in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, subset

I have a dataframe that looks like so:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Location = c("buildinga", "buildinga", "buildinga", "buildingb", "buildingb", "buildingb", "buildingc", "buildingc", "buildingc),
  Category   = c(candy, candy, snacks, candy, snacks, soda, soda, candy, soda)
  Calories   = 200, 250, 150, 180, 200, 80, 140, 200, 210)
)
```

I want to group 'Location' by just a single building and pull corresponding values for each location (so building a, b and c have total calories for candy, snacks, and soda).

I tried doing group_by(location) %>% summarize(count(n=()) but that still gave me each location. I want to remove duplicates for location but not for 'Category' or 'Calories'.

Comment: What is the expected output.  Your example iis giving me errors.  Please fix it

Comment: Perhaps `df %>% group_by(Location) %>% summarise(count = n_distinct(Category))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `base R` to find the `sum` of 'Calories' grouped by other columns

```
aggregate(Calories ~ ., df, FUN = sum)
#   Location Category Calories
#1 buildinga    candy      450
#2 buildingb    candy      180
#3 buildingc    candy      200
#4 buildinga   snacks      150
#5 buildingb   snacks      200
#6 buildingb     soda       80
#7 buildingc     soda      350
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Location = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("buildinga", "buildingb", "buildingc"
), class = "factor"), Category = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("candy", "snacks", "soda"), 
class = "factor"), 
    Calories = c(200, 250, 150, 180, 200, 80, 140, 200, 210)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: Perfect, instead of sum would I use max if i wanted to find the most calorie based product out of all of them? My goal is to group products by performance (worst/best performer, cost, etc. per building.).

Comment: @Dinho If you need to group, then probably, `cut` would be better `with(df, ave(Calories, Location, Category, FUN = function(x) cut(x, breaks = 3, labels = c("worst", "moderate", "best"))))`

Comment: @Dinho Or with `dplyr` `df %>% group_by(Location, Category) %>% mutate(group = cut(Calories, breaks = 3, labels = c("worst", "moderate", "best")))`

Comment: thanks @akrun. What exactly is your worst, moderate, and best factoring in to consider it that? Also, is there a way to group all building a's into just one building value? Basically the multiple building values per group (a, b, or c) represent floors. If I wanted a global average, max, and min value for just the building (taking in each floor), how would I reformat the df to get that? I can't seem to get it..

Comment: @Dinho You can pass the breaks for average, max, min value i.e. `df %>%group_by(Location, Category) %>%  mutate(group = cut(Calories, breaks = c(min(Calories), mean(Calories), max(Calories)), labels = c("worst", "moderate", "best")))`

Comment: I ran your code but looked at total_sales and got this error df <- updated_df %>% group_by(Location, `Category Name`) %>% mutate(group = cut(Total_Sales, breaks = c(min(Total_Sales), mean(Total_Sales), max(Total_Sales)), labels = c("worst", "moderate", "best")))
Error in cut.default(Total_Sales, breaks = c(min(Total_Sales), mean(Total_Sales),  : 
  'breaks' are not unique

Comment: @Dinho That couldd be a case when a group have only a single unique value

Answer (score 4):

Using `dplyr`, you can `group_by` your data and count calories in each category.

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Location, Category) %>%
  summarise(Count = sum(Calories))

# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   Location [3]
  Location  Category Count
  <fct>     <fct>    <dbl>
1 buildinga candy      450
2 buildinga snacks     150
3 buildingb candy      180
4 buildingb snacks     200
5 buildingb soda        80
6 buildingc candy      200
7 buildingc soda       350
```

Is it what you are looking for ?

**Data**

Your data examples has some typo issues, here is the one that I used:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  Location = c("buildinga", "buildinga", "buildinga", "buildingb", "buildingb", "buildingb", "buildingc", "buildingc", "buildingc"),
  Category   = c("candy", "candy", "snacks", "candy", "snacks", "soda", "soda", "candy", "soda"),
  Calories   = c(200, 250, 150, 180, 200, 80, 140, 200, 210)
)
```

Comment: Perfect, instead of sum would I use max if i wanted to find the most calorie based product out of all of them? My goal is to group products by performance (worst/best performer, cost, etc. per building.).

Comment: @Dinho, sure, you can either replace `sum` by `max` if you want the maximum for each group products, you can also have both by doing `summarise(Count = sum(Calories), Max = max(Calories))`.

Comment: See @akrun comment in his answer, it will give you the desired output

Answer (score 2):

Hi it sounds like you want something like this:

```
df %>% group_by(Location, Category) %>% summarise(total_cal = sum(Calories))
```

This is long format and I think you are going for wide format?

```
df %>% spread(key = Category, value = total_cal, fill = 0)
```

If you want, you could also transpose it.